# Why socket.io server dont receive the connection from android studio client?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, kotlin, socket.io

im stuck with trying to set connection between my socket.io server on node js (socket.io ver:4.7.2) to android studio (socket ver:2.0.0), can someone help resolve this problem? When i updating the activity nothing happend on server

server:

```
const express = require('express'); //requires express module
const socket = require('socket.io'); //requires socket.io module
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(PORT); //tells to host server on localhost:3000


//Playing variables:
app.use(express.static('public')); //show static files in 'public' directory
console.log('Server is running');
const io = socket(server);

//Socket.io Connection------------------
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('Client connected.');

    // Disconnect listener
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('Client disconnected.');
    });
});
```

client:
SocketHandler.kt

```
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket
import java.net.URISyntaxException

object SocketHandler {

    lateinit var mSocket: Socket

    @Synchronized
    fun setSocket() {
        try {
// "http://10.0.2.2:3000" is the network your Android emulator must use to join the localhost network on your computer
// "http://localhost:3000/" will not work
// If you want to use your physical phone you could use your ip address plus :3000
// This will allow your Android Emulator and physical device at your home to connect to the server
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://0.0.0.0:3000")
        } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {

        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun getSocket(): Socket {
        return mSocket
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun establishConnection() {
        mSocket.connect()
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun closeConnection() {
        mSocket.disconnect()
    }
}
```

ActivityCode

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:   Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

*        SocketHandler.setSocket()
        val mSocket = SocketHandler.getSocket()
        mSocket.connect()*

        val Dec_button = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.login_button)
        Dec_button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, LoginPage::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Im was trynna to rebooting, changing the local ip's adress (in activity), googling

Comment: Please edit your question and describe in detail the network configuration your PC and the Android device is located in (or are you using the android emulator)? Also include the IP address of the PC the socket.io server is listening on.

Comment: im using android emulator, and i idk how to get the "IP address of the PC the socket.io server is listening on", if it's local ip - i used it...

Comment: Even if the Android Emulator runs inside your PC it emulates a complete Android phone which means this phone has it's own IP stack and thus it's own "localhost". Use "10.0.2.2" as alreayd shown in the comment of your app code as IP address to connect to. BTW. A client socket can never connect to "0.0.0.0" this IP is only usable for the server.

Comment: worked..........

Comment: Now that you know this troubleshooting step was the solution to your problem, consider phrasing @Robert's comment as a complete answer to your question here.